# Starting process from .NET app and Attachment Execution Service

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security, process

I'm using VLC player for playing videos from my WPF app (vlc palyer is distributed with app) It is possible to avoid alert "Open File - Security Warnng" during first start of video (vlc) on new machine without changing system settings?

I'm using this code for starting VLC:

```
var vlcArgs = string.Format("\"{0}\" --config=\"{1}\" -Incurse --play-and-exit",
   videoFilePath, vlcConfigPath);

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"vlc\vlc.exe", vlcArgs);
VlcProcess = Process.Start(psi);
```

I found that

> Every script or program that is run by using the ShellExecute() API
>   passes through AES

So, if I set `UseShellExecute` property of `ProcessStartInfo` object to false, will it help? Or any other idea how to avoid AES check?

[image: warning]

Comment: It may be worth considering embedding the video player in your application using a wrapper for VLC such as Vlc.DotNet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/). This should help to keep your interface consistent and provide additional control over your video playback.

Comment: @goobering Thanks, we used Vlc.DotNet in our app for a long time, but we had serious problems with memory leaks (https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/issues/68) so we decided to temporary use this not very elegant solution/workaround (I hope that memory leaks will be fixed in next relases of Vlc.DotNet and we will move back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CreateProcess Instead of ShellExecute. Can you try the below code?

```
var vlcArgs = string.Format("\"{0}\" --config=\"{1}\" -Incurse --play-and-exit",
   videoFilePath, vlcConfigPath);

var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"vlc\vlc.exe", vlcArgs);
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
VlcProcess = Process.Start(psi);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

If proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute is false, then you are launching the process and can use:

```
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

If proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute is true,

```
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```